# Error "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ISTAlertView", referenced from:"

Tags: iphone, cocoa

When I am compiling my code I am getting this kinda errors...
_OBJC_CLASS_$_ISTAlertView", referenced from:

Any clue what could be the reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That error shows up when the .m file containing `ISTAlertView` is not being compiled into the target.  The file may be there or it may not be; it's just not getting compiled.  If this is from a library, then you're not linking in the library, so the compiler doesn't know where to go to find the `ISTAlertView` class.

If the file is yours, find it and "Get Info" on it in Xcode.  Then go to the "Targets" tab and make sure the checkbox is checked next to the target the file is supposed to be in.  If it's already checked, then clean your build and try again.

If it's in a library, then make sure the library is part of the "Link binary with libraries" phase of your target compilation.

Answer (score 0):

The code file ISTAlertView.h and possibly also ISTAlertView.m are not present in your project. Right click on your classes folder and select "add Existing files". Navigate to your Classes folder and check if you can find them there. If not, go looking under the desk :)

Answer (score 0):

It's only .m file that is missing... You didn't provide details about your project, but it if this source in the static library be sure you link it with the project, where the calling source reside. Of and referenced from... which you omitted can tell you which source uses functions from ISTAlertView.m.